# Swift - Taking a value from a cell that's being deleted and applying it elsewhere

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm a beginner with Swift.

I'm building a budgeting app for practice and I made a purchase history using a TableView with custom cells that contain 4 labels--amount spent, description, date, and a hidden tag to mark which category the purchase was made (For example, a "1" might indicate that an entry was made in the food category).

I'm trying to implement a way for the user to delete a cell from the spending history, and based on the tag of the entry that is being deleted, have the amount spent be returned to the appropriate category.

Comment: Cells are only for display. You should operate any adding/removing/returning value from the model (for example the array containing the objects displayed in the cells), not from the cell itself. Each cell should correspond to an object in the array. If the user does something in a cell, you do something in the corresponding object in the array using the row index.

Answer (score 0):

When you displaying data in cell you fill labels with data by index of this cell. So you can get this data by cell index. So when cell deleting you know indexPaht for this cell.

Comment: You can simply delete index of deleted item from array and reload the tableview cell will be deleted automatically(actually cell is not deleted)